# Controller to view passing an array

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have this line of code in my controller:

```
$this->load->view('sampleview',$result);
```

So when I go into my view and try to `echo` result, either by `foreach` or directly writing

```
print_r($result);
```

it shows an error that it is an undefined variable.

But when I put the `print_r($result);` on my controller like this below:

```
function show()
{
$this->load->view('sampleview',$result);
print_r($result);
}
```

It would print on my `sampleview` page where I was redirected. I’m confused why this is happening.

**EDIT**

The whole controller would be: I have another view which I click an anchor tag with `segment(3)` as an id. Then I query that id to my model then pass it to another view for display.

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$result = $this->model->show($recipe_id);
        if($result!=null)
        {   
            $this->load->view('Admin_recipe_edit',$result);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `$result` array will be extracted in your `view`. if you want as an array, then do it as

```
$data["result"] = $result;
$this->load->view('sampleview',$data);
```

Then do `print_r($result);` in view.

Comment: Ah, yes, It was extracted. Thanks for your answer. now i can continue :) i will accept it as soon as stackoverflow lets me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should have to make a array of data that you want to access on your view

```
// Your array
$result['Data_Array'] = array(....);
$this->load->view('sampleview',$result);
print_r($result);
```

Now Access like this in your View Section:

### View

```
print_r($Data_Array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude try to put $result in an array example`$view_data['$result']=$result;` then load the view exmaple `$this->load->view(your_view,$view_data);`. and in the view page try to print $result.exmaple `print_r($result);` .It will work I think so.

Comment: I forgot that CI automatically extracts the values i had in my array.

still, thanks for the heads up. i wont forget it this time.

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter

```
$Data['result'] = $ArrayData;
$this->load->view('viewfile',$Data);
```

In View

```
print_r($result);
```